# Content specific page titles in UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, page-title

When using UI-Router, how do you handle content specific page titles?

I can handle normal page titles just fine, for example:

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
        "navbar": {
            template: normalNavbarTemplate
        },
        "content": {
            template: '<login authenticated="(bCtrl.userSession && bCtrl.userSession.isAuthenticated)"></login>'
        }
    },
    title: 'My Website (0.2) - Login'
})
```

And then:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (evt, toState) {
    $window.document.title = toState.title;
});
```

But what happens when you want your title to include content specific content, which you are obtaining using *resolve*?

I guess you can inject *$window* into your components, and set the title that way, but it feels messy. Are there any nicer recipes for this which I may have missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the title property inside the resolve:

```
resolve: {
    content: function($http) {
        return $http.get('some_url').then(function(result) {

            this.self.title = result.data.title; // set the title property to whatever you like

            return result;
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know you could do that, that is awesome!

Comment: I use it to set permissions on views, and it is indeed awesome :)

Comment: Totally, what is the deal with *bind(this)*. I don't use that normally in resolves, is that important for setting page titles?

Comment: If you won't `.bind(this)` to the `then(function() {})`, the `this` won't be that of the view.

Comment: Ok cool, I'm guessing that's something true to Javascript generally?

Comment: ie. not an angular specific thing?

Comment: You are guessing right. Indeed it is - [Array.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).